# How do I add a selectable text in HTML 5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to place a text label on top of a canvas. Is it possible? How can I do that?
I know there's fillText but fillText is not giving me smooth output text. I also want the text on the label to be copyable by the users, which is not possible if I use fillText.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming, you simply want to place some text on top of the canvas in an html page :

**HTML:**

```
<label>Yahoo, I'm on top of canvas??</label>
<canvas width="500" height="500" ></canvas>
```

**CSS:**

```
canvas {
    border:1px solid gray;
}

label {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
}
```

<kbd>**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HBpnc/)**</kbd>

---

**EDIT:**

As per the edit, if you are looking for a solution to select text inside canvas, it would be a bit more pain full.

I would suggest using <kbd>**[CreateJS](http://createjs.com/)**</kbd>. It would make your life whole lot easier while working with canvas.

Although the library does not provide you with a selectable text, but it is easier to implement.

Here is a <kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HPx38/1/)**</kbd> of how you could create a selectable text.

```
// Text Selector Class
function Selector(stage, text) {
    var select = new createjs.Shape();

    function selector(x, y, width, height) {
        select.graphics.clear().beginFill("#ace")
            .drawRect(x || 0, y || 0, width || 0, height || 0);
    }
    var tuw = text.getMeasuredWidth();
    var tuh = text.getMeasuredHeight();
    text.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
        var startX = e.rawX;
        var onMove = function (e) {
            if (e.rawX >= text.x && e.rawX <= text.x + tuw) selector(startX, text.y, e.rawX - startX, tuh);
        };
        var onUp = function () {
            stage.removeEventListener("stagemousemove", onMove);
            selector();
        };
        stage.addEventListener("stagemousemove", onMove);
        stage.addEventListener("stagemouseup", onUp);
    });
    return select;
}


var stage = new createjs.Stage("shape");

// Text Node
var text = new createjs.Text("Hello World");
text.x = 100;
text.font = "20px Arial";
text.color = "#ff7700";
text.cursor = "text";
stage.addChild(text);

// Attach Selector 
stage.addChildAt(new Selector(stage, text), 0);

// Important
stage.enableMouseOver();
setInterval(function () {
    stage.update();
}, 100);
```

Comment: I think he was looking for something analogous to fillText that actually draws the label onto the canvas...

Comment: @richthepanda Perhaps yes. I've edited my answer to include another demo.

Comment: I know this is pretty old already but I'm completely stuck on how to actually get the selected value out of your example. To my eyes it looks like it just draws rectangle behind the text but doesn't actually deal with characters themselves making it hard to extract them.

Comment: @loxxy, There's a bit of **lag** with the selection.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Here's an example using an `svg` with a `foreignObject` straight from the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p><canvas id="canvas" style="border:2px solid black;" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>" +
         "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
           "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='font-size:40px'>" +
             "<em>I</em> like <span style='color:white; text-shadow:0 0 2px blue;'>cheese</span>" +
           "</div>" +
         "</foreignObject>" +
       "</svg>";
  var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
  var img = new Image();
  var svg = new Blob([data], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
  var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
  img.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  };
  img.src = url;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That text is not actually selectable.

Comment: Yep. The original question has been edited. It was originally "how do I place a label on an HTML 5 canvas?"

Answer (score 1):

In one of my canvas projects I needed to create highlight-able, editable, and copy-able text area generated on click and removed when the text area loses focus. Below is the structure of how I did it

Javascript:

```
var mousePos;
var textarea = null;  
var x;
var y;
var textValue;
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) 
{
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) 
 {
   mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
   mouseDown = true;
   setTimeout(function() { check(mousePos.x, mousePos.y) }, 50);  
 }, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(evt) 
 {
   evt.preventDefault();
   mouseDown = false;
 }, false);

function check(xPos, yPos)
{
  if(xPos > /*lower bounding x position*/ && xPos < /*upper bounding x position*/ && yPos < /*upper bounding y position*/ && yPos > /*lower bounding y position*/)
  {
    if(!textarea) {
      textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
      textarea.className = 'textArea';
      textarea.onkeypress = function (e) {
        if (e.which === 13) { // Allows pressing 'Enter' to change the focus of the text area
          textarea.blur();
        }
      }
      textarea.onblur = function () {
        /*do something with value*/
        textValue = textarea.value;
        document.body.removeChild(textarea);
        textarea = null;
      } 
      document.body.appendChild(textarea);
    }
    textarea.blur();
    textarea.value = /*put default value*/;
    textarea.style.left = /*put left position of object*/;
    textarea.style.top = /*put top position of object*/;        
  }
}
```

CSS

```
.textArea {
  /* The only necessary CSS is a height, a width, and position:absolute */
  position: absolute;
  background:grey;
  height:20px;
  border:0;
  outline:0;
  line-height:10px;
  width:100px;
  resize: none;
  overflow:hidden;
  font-size:10px;
}
```

This allows only one text area to be created and is created on click and removed when it loses focus. Not sure if you want this functionality, but it's easy to remove if not

[Demo here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/canvasgui) (WiP) when you click on the value to the right of one of the bars